# Google blogger with ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, google-api

I am planned to use google blogger feature with our ruby on rails application. I get the blogger API key from google developer console. Is there any gem for this concept. I refer and get the gem 'google-api-client', '~> 0.9'. Is this useful to integrate google blogger with rails??? And give some javascript to use google blogger with rails.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch the post of blog you can use gem [bloggerapi](https://rubygems.org/gems/bloggerapi)

Or you can use gem [blogger](https://rubygems.org/gems/blogger)